# Functions orthogonal to x^n

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I would like to ask if there are any set of functions $u_n(x)$ which is orthogonal to $x^n$?
i.e.:

$\int_0^1 x^n u_m(x) dx = \delta_{n,m}$

Edit: For clarification, this question asked for all non-negative integer m and n.

Comment: You should be able to prove easily that a continuous function which is orthogonal to all xn  is zero. Using that, you can answer your question. (This applies to continuous functions; if you want other kind of regularity, well, you'll have to adapt the argument)

Comment: the answers seem to reflect some confusion over whether the orthogonality is also over all n or is fixed for each n.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $f \in L^2([0, 1])$ and $\int_0^1 x^n f(x)\, dx=0$ for all $n\ge N$ where $N$ is a nonnegative integer then $f$ is zero almost everywhere. To see this note that $x\mapsto x^N f(x)$ is an $L^2$ function orthogonal to all polynomials, and the polynomials are dense in $L^2([0,1])$. So the answer to your question is "no" for $L^2$ functions.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. A follow up question: what if the interval changes? maybe to [-1,1] , or other interval?

Comment: The argument remains exactly the same for any bounded interval.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, and the main reason is that $\{x^n\}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ form a total set in $L^2([0,1])$ so the set of their finite linear combinations is dense. But $\int x^n dx > 0$ for $n \geq 0$.

I believe, the best one can do is apply Gram--Schmidt to $x^n$ and obtain a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ (the orthogonal polynomials) of degree $n$ such that
$$
 p_n \perp x^m,\quad m > n.
$$
Here $f \perp g$ means $\int f(x) g(x)  dx= 0$.

However, the notion of "best" here is not well-defined. It's just the usual choice.

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives of the Dirac distribution (appropriately normalized).

Comment: I believe the question was about functions, not distributions.